# WordPress custom post type Single.php?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have a WordPress custom post-type setup. I've created

```
single-[customposttype].php
```

However instead of displaying only the requested custom-post-type it goes to the URL, then displays all of the posts in the custom-type.

Here's a copy of the code i'm currently using:

```
    <?php query_posts("post_type=shorts"); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="header-promo">
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "mo_short_embed", true); ?>
</div>
<div class="content-details">   
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Questions like this are ideal for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Andy I've posted this question over there as well (http://bit.ly/c0q3WR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was to remove

```
query_posts("post_type=shorts");
```

This is only needed for pulling in multiple posts of a custom-post-types, e.g. to create an Archives-style page.

Comment: Ah, makes sense since pulling the post type on a custom slug is redundant. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "posts_per_page" and setting it to 1.

```
query_posts(
 'post_type' => 'shorts',
 'posts_per_page' => 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this takes the first post from the 'shorts' post-type, not the one selected.